How can i move content of dir1 in myRepo1 git to another directory in another myRepo2 i.e. move content of myRepo1/dir1 to myRepo2/dir2
I want to achieve
repo-1
---- dir1
--- content of dir1
repo-2
---- dir2
--- content of dir1 from repo-1
We have many references available to mode content of directory to new repo but not to the sub-directory of new Repo.
I need to move content of dir1 in myRepo1 git to another directory in another myRepo2 i.e. move content of myRepo1/dir1 to myRepo2/dir2 by preserving the commit history.
git read-tree with --prefix is doing the job but not preserving the history.
git pull i can only do on parent folder with .git file exists.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359424/detach-move-subdirectory-into-separate-git-repository/ cd Repo1 && git subtree push -P dir1 Repo2 Repo1/dir1; the last Repo1/dir1 is a new branch in Repo2 which you can merge/rebase how you want.

Thanks, but my folder name is different I need to move content of dir1 in repo1 TO dir2 of repo2.. in the answer above i see the folder is same ABC.

Rename it in Repo2 after pushing. Or do it in a long complex way: git subtree push to a new empty repo, run git filter-repo to rename dir1 to dir2 in all commits, the pull the new repo into Repo2.

filter-repo is helpful, Thanks

Try this;
Clone myRepo1 to your local machine if you haven't already.
Clone myRepo2 to your local machine.
Navigate to myRepo1: cd myRepo1..
Add dir1 and its content to the staging area: git add dir1/*..
Commit the changes with a descriptive message: git commit -m "Move dir1 content to myRepo2".
Navigate to myRepo2: cd ../myRepo2.
Use git subtree merge to add the content of dir1 to dir2: git subtree merge --prefix=dir2 ../myRepo1/dir1 master
How it works;
git subtree merge is a powerful command that allows you to integrate a subdirectory from another Git repository into the current one.
--prefix=dir2 tells git subtree merge to add the content of dir1 under the directory named dir2 in myRepo2.
../myRepo1/dir1 specifies the source subdirectory (relative path from your current location).
master specifies the branch in myRepo1 that you want to integrate (replace with the desired branch if needed).
Lastly, Push the changes to myRepo2: git push origin master. This approach will preserve the commit history of dir1 within myRepo2.
Note:
Make sure you have made any necessary pulls or fetches in both repositories before performing these steps.
If dir2 already exists in myRepo2, its contents will be overwritten by dir1.

yes it helps, thanks for elaborated answer.

while trying this i am getting error, fatal: master: no such path in the working tree, as there is no .git dir in myRepo1/dir1
